# maven-release-plugin goals ignored in submodule in multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a multi-module Maven project. The project is laid out as follows

```
project/
  pom.xml

  types/
    pom.xml

  client/
    pom.xml

  service/
    pom.xml
```

The `types` and `client` modules are built as JARs, `service` is built as a WAR. I'm using the maven-release-plugin to create new releases of this project. I would *like* to have the release plugin invoke extra goals when performing the release of the `service` module.

The release plugin is configured like so in the root pom (nothing special):

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.3</version>
</plugin>
```

... and configured like so in the `service` pom along with the plugin I'm trying to invoke via the `<goals>` parameter:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <goals>deploy dockerfile:build dockerfile:push</goals>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <repository>12345.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/project</repository>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The idea is that I'd like to build a Docker image for the `service` module but it doesn't make sense to build images for other modules in the project. However, when cutting a new release, the goals configuration in the `service` pom file are never invoked.

Maven version: 3.3.3

maven-release-plugin: 2.5.3

JDK: Oracle 1.8.0u144

The command being used:

```
mvn -Pstaging -B clean release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

I'm not able to share the output from this command.

I've verified that the relevant configurations seem be be applied via

```
mvn -Pstaging help:effective-pom
```

My question is: Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible with the release plugin? I haven't found any questions or articles that indicate it's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that I have never used the `dockerfile-maven-plugin`, try release profiles instead of goals.

Step 1. Edit the release plugin config in `project/pom.xml`.

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.3</version>   <!-- should define in pluginManagement -->
  <configuration>
    <releaseProfiles>publish-docker</releaseProfiles>
    <!-- other plugin config -->
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Choose a name for the profile that makes sense. I'll use publish-docker as the name here.

Step 2. Add a profile with that name to `service/pom.xml`:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>publish-docker</id>
    <build>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <repository>12345.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/project</repository>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>docker-publish</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>  <!-- important -->
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>push</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

This profile includes plugin configuration that binds the `dockerfile:build` and `dockerfile:push` goals to the `deploy` phase. The release plugin will enable the publish-docker profile for each module. The profile will only exist in the `service` module, so that's where it will run.

One other thing I notice. In the release command:

```
mvn -Pstaging -B clean release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

I suspect the `-Pstaging` part is not actually being applied during the release. The release plugin forks another process for each goal run. To pass the argument to the fork, the `arguments` parameter is required:

```
mvn -Pstaging -Darguments="-Pstaging" -B clean release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```